# Redirect из контроллера в Laravel 5

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

Задача из скрипта послать AJAX запрос на удаление записи в БД и вернуться на главную страницу.

Роуты:

```
Route::get('/', 'MasterController@index')->name('main');
Route::delete('/organisation/{id}', 'OrganisationController@destroy')
```

JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({ headers: {
         'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
         url: model+"/"+id,
         type: 'delete',
      });
```

Контроллер:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $organisation = Organisation::find($id);
    $organisation->delete();

    return redirect('/');
}
```

Запись удаляется, но при редиректе из контроллера появляется ошибка

```
"exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\MethodNotAllowedHttpException",
```

так как в типа запроса остается DELETE и Laravel соответственно не может найти такого роута.

```
Request URL: http://app/
Request Method: DELETE
Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed
```

Есть ли возможность перенаправиться на главную страницу из контроллера?

Comment: а return __redirect()->back()__ не вариант??

Comment: такой же результат, запрос отсылается методом DELETE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В контроллере вернуть роут:

```
return route('main');
```

В скрипте, после выполнения сделать переадресацию:

```
$.ajax({ headers: {
     'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
     url: model+"/"+id,
     type: 'delete',
     success: function(route){
         location.replace(route);
     }
});
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, работает